# Combine cross reference to multiple figures

Tags: errors, cross-referencing, plot, cleveref, journal-publishing

I am writing a paper in [Automatica journal](http://www.journals.elsevier.com/automatica/) format. The sample and style file can be found [here](http://www.autsubmit.com/documents/LaTeXstylefiles.html).

I want to use a cross reference to serveral figures such as `Fig.~\ref{fig:aaa,fig:bbb,fig:ccc}` and get `Fig. 1-3` as result. Some people on web suggest `cleveref` package. My problem is that `cleveref` crashes when it is used with the style of this journal with the following error:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. }{}
```

[image: Latex error]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{autart}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}
\lstset{tabsize=2}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hhline}
%\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Title, Title, Title, Title, Title, Title}

\begin{keyword}
aa, bb, cc
\end{keyword}  

\begin{abstract}
abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, abstract, 
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}

Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, Introduction, 

\section{part1}

See Fig.~\ref{aaa,bbb,ccc}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{aaa}
    \caption{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}
    \label{fig:aaa}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{bbb}
    \caption{bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb}
    \label{fig:bbb}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{ccc}
    \caption{cccccccccccccccccccc}
    \label{fig:ccc}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It gets into an infinite loop expanding \cl@part ->\cl@part \@elt {section}.

Comment: AFAICT, the only thing unusual about autart is that it uses "part" and "section" but not "chapter".

Comment: Aha!  Add \newcounter{part} right after \documentclass{autart}.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, Thanks, worked perfect. please leave it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this qualifies as a bug in `autart.cls`.  There is no `\part` defined, although `\@addtoreset{section}{part}`, `\def\partname{Part}` and `\def\lb@part{PART \thepart.\half@em}` are used.

I modified the MWE to make it more minimal.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{autart}
\newcounter{part}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{How I Got Away}
\author{C. W. Coop}
\begin{abstract}
Jumping from a 727 is not as easy as it might first appear.
\end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}

\section{Bring your own parachute}
\end{document}
```